# git reset can't work when commited with force push

Tags: git

I have forgotten to update my local repo with git pull and i commited to a file `myfile.py` and then pushed them with `git push -f upstream master`

Later i realised it and tried to reset to the commit id but after resetting found that it isn't showing the files which i have committed to the remote upstream (it's just the files in my local repo, with the commited `myfile.py`)

Anyway to reset to the point before it was commited with `git push -f upstream master`

Comment: Can you add a picture of your output from `git log` so we can better see what the history looks like? For the sake of the future, stop using `git push -f`. If you didn't use `-f` to force push it would have aborted and told you that you needed to pull first.

Comment: @DrZoo strange it shows no commits of today the last commit commit on top is of 25th Nov and my name there is MissAlexaRobot but my name on github is MissJuliaRobot(which i changed long days ago than 25th Nov)

Comment: i don't have much reputation to include a picture see this https://telegra.ph/git-log-11-28

Comment: Do you still need help with the issue? I didn't get to look at it yet, but noticed that a telethonbot in git has been updated recently with a username like yours. I didn't know if that was the correct one.

Comment: @DrZoo thanks but i have solved my problem (it was my good luck tho) actually the bot was deployed to heroku and i am able to extract the last updated files from there and upload it via the telegram bot itself 

Comment: Cross-posted verbatim from Stack Overflow: [git reset can't work when commited with force push](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65046729/4642212).